# How to create PDF using PdfSharp which includes grid and images using c#

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

I want to generate PDF report of my invoice page which includes telerik grids, images etc controls and i want to create PDf with all these controls.

If anyone can provide demo that it would be great.

One more thing that in pdf generate code for all labels have to specify perfect x-axis and y-axis. Is there any way that PdfSharp will render labels aumatically?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: How about searching in google, there a lots of sample for that

Comment: I have searched it but did not found proper example for same. If you have any then let me know